# CalendarPickerView is return null value in Vivo device

Tags: android, calendar

[After select the date ,the EditText is not showing the selected date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn5N1.gif)

this the methos implemented to show the calender popup

```
 private void calendarShowPopup(Activity context) { /* calling calenderview Popup*/
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View calendarPopup = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.calender_popup, null, false);

    Display display = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    int width;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT> Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2){
        display.getSize(size);
        width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;
    }else{
        width = display.getHeight();
    }
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(calendarPopup, width - 20, width);

    popupWindow.setContentView(calendarPopup);
    popupWindow.setHeight(width);

    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

    popupWindow.showAtLocation(calendarPopup, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

    final ParentEyeCalendarView calendar = (ParentEyeCalendarView) calendarPopup.findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);
    Calendar previousMonth = Calendar.getInstance();
    previousMonth.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0);

    Calendar nextMonth = Calendar.getInstance();
    nextMonth.add(Calendar.MONTH, 12);


    calendar.setCustomDayView(new DefaultDayViewAdapter());
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    try {
        DatetoDisplay = df.parse(submissionDate.getText().toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (DatetoDisplay == null)
        DatetoDisplay = new Date();

    calendar.setDecorators(Collections.<CalendarCellDecorator>emptyList());

           calendar.setOnInvalidDateSelectedListener(new CalendarPickerView.OnInvalidDateSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onInvalidDateSelected(Date date) {
    Toast.makeText(ComposeHomeworkActivity.this, "You have selected an invalid date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} });

     calendar.initializeWithSingleDate(previousMonth.getTime(), nextMonth.getTime(), DatetoDisplay);
     Button done = (Button) calendarPopup.findViewById(R.id.done_button);
    done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String selectedDate="";
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE LLL dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-LLL-yy");
            Date dateFormat;
            try {
                dateFormat = df.parse(calendar.getSelectedDate().toString());
                selectedDate = formatter.format(dateFormat);
                DatetoDisplay = dateFormat;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            submissionDate.setText(selectedDate);
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

This is the CalendarPickerView extends class

```
 public class ParentEyeCalendarView extends CalendarPickerView {
public ParentEyeCalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void setCustomDayView(DayViewAdapter dayViewAdapter) {
    super.setCustomDayView(dayViewAdapter);
}

@Override
public void setDecorators(List<CalendarCellDecorator> decorators) {
    super.setDecorators(decorators);
}

@Override
public void setOnInvalidDateSelectedListener(OnInvalidDateSelectedListener listener) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You have selected an invalid date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
public void initializeWithSingleDate(Date minDate,Date maxDate,Date selectedDate){
    init(minDate,maxDate).inMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE).withSelectedDate(selectedDate);
}
public void initializeWithMultipleDate(Date minDate,Date maxDate,ArrayList<Date> selectedDates){
    init(minDate, maxDate).inMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE).withSelectedDates(selectedDates);
}

@Override
public Date getSelectedDate() {
    return super.getSelectedDate();
}}
```

**The same code is working with other device like redmi devices,samsung devices and also tried with android studio emulators is working fine.**
** Any solution **

Comment: You should try to log the exception that you catch in the `onClick` of the button with id `R.id.done_button` and let us know what you get

Comment: I found the problem here the user is using regional language as the device language . so instead of  " SimpleDateFormat("dd-LLL-yy") "  am used SimpleDateFormat("dd-LLL-yy",Locale.ENGLISH) is working fine.